# WSL2 network unreachable for any distro

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

A couple of weeks ago, WSL suddenly could not reach any IP addresses nor resolve any domains.  Even internal network IPs are not reachable.

```
>lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

❯ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               klewis@NOTEBOOK-KLEWIS
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ----------------------
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 1 hour, 20 mins
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 1405 (dpkg)
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: zsh 5.8
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Adwaita [GTK3]
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Icons: Adwaita [GTK3]
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: Windows Terminal
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: Intel i7-7820HK (8) @ 2.903GHz
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Memory: 968MiB / 5942MiB
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Font: Cantarell 11 [GTK3]
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Wlinux

`````
❯ neofetch

                                ..,   klewis@LAPTOP-FLQBDPP8
                    ....,,:;+ccllll   ----------------------
      ...,,+:;  cllllllllllllllllll   OS: Pengwin on Windows 10 x86_64
,cclllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   Kernel: 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   Uptime: 30 mins
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   Packages: 353 (dpkg)
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   Shell: bash 5.1.4
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   Terminal: Windows Terminal
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll   CPU: Intel i7-10750H (12) @ 2.592GHz
                                      Memory: 106MiB / 25464MiB
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
llllllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
`'ccllllllllll  lllllllllllllllllll
       `' \*::  :ccllllllllllllllll
                       ````''*::cll
                                 ``
`````

```
❯ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.106.224  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.25.111.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe6f:8b36  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:6f:8b:36  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3488  bytes 468708 (468.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 1842 (1.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

❯ ccat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 9.9.9.9

❯ ccat /etc/wsl.conf
[user]
default=klewis

# Now make it look like this and save the file when you're done:
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"

[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

```
❯ ping 127.0.0.1
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
❯ ping 192.168.0.1
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
❯ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
❯ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
❯ nslookup google.com 9.9.9.9
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

❯ ip route
default via 172.25.96.1 dev eth0
172.25.96.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.106.224

❯ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:4a:7c:75:0f:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:8a:00:5a:47:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:6f:8b:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.106.224/20 brd 172.25.111.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe6f:8b36/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

```
C:\> ipconfig
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-3D-76-44
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85c9:71dc:b691:4da2%63(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.25.96.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1056970077
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-27-6E-E5-67-54-05-DB-FD-51-82
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

```
>sudo ip route add default via 192.168.16.1
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
```

I have looked through GH and found solutions that worked for others.  Things I have tried:

- ```
  netsh winsock reset
  netsh int ip reset all
  netsh winhttp reset proxy
  ipconfig /flushdns
  ```
- deleted Hyper-V virtual adapters and restarting to let Windows rebuild
- Changed where the Virtual Switch connects to in Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager from Internal Network to External Network
- Ensured %TEMP% is not compressed
- Ensured no file nor folder under %TEMP% were compressed
- Ensured no firewall was running
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4926
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4731
- turned off Generation of resolv.conf and add gateway, 9.9.9.9 and 8.8.8.8 to resolv.conf

```
❯ ccat /etc/hosts

# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       LAPTOP-FLQBDPP8.localdomain     LAPTOP-FLQBDPP8

192.168.0.174   host.docker.internal
192.168.0.174   gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Your DNS providers is basically set to IPv6 equivalent of localhost.  Your IPv4 address assigned to WSL is a completely separate subnet than 192.168.0.1 which by default explains why that connection is inaccessible.  The commands you have issued outside of WSL only effect Windows not WSL.  Have you tried to reset your WSL2 configuration?  If there is something valuable you can export the current configuration, as a backup, to see if the problem is the current configuration or not. As a test set `generateHosts` to true and post the /etc/hosts` that is generated. also run `wsl.exe --shutdown`

Comment: @Ramhound done.  And to my knowledge, WSL doesn't have a singular configuration besides the Windows HyperV networking stack that gets auto-gen'd by WIndows.  So if there were Linux configuration issues, they would be affecting a singular distro, not all distros (even newly created ones).  So the problem almost has to be in the Windows stack somewhere (again, unless I am grossly misunderstanding how this works).

Comment: Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default shipped with Windows?  If so, does completely uninstalling it and rebooting fix the problem?

Comment: I am now, uninstalling has no effect and it wasn't installed when issues first arose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of build 19042.1052, this is working again with no changes from my end. I am unsure as to the actual cause, but since I can no longer reproduce it, further troubleshooting seems moot.