# WSL2 Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, windows, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

My WSL2 can't connect with internet on any distro. Network is unreachable on `sudo apt-get update`. I don't have any VPN just fresh Windows 11 or 10. It's wired connection using Wifi Router, It can connect with internet If I use the wire directly from the wifi [Onu Device](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51xiSpz7ugL._SL1200_.jpg) Device instead of Router. Similar to this image below:

[image: Wired Connection]

Now it's from Wifi Router below:
[image: Wired Connection by Router]

This is my `ipconfig` output:
[image: ipconfig output]

```
OS: Windows 11 (Up to date)
Distro: Ubuntu (WSL 2)
```

Things I tried and failed:

- [WSL2 Network Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66338549/wsl2-network-unreachable)
- [Github WSL #5336](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336)
- [Github WSL #4275](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4275)
- [WSL2 Network Unreachable for any distro](https://superuser.com/questions/1648090/wsl2-network-unreachable-for-any-distro)
- [No internet connection on wsl ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux/64057835#64057835)
  and so on...

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: So you do have Internet connection on the Windows/host side with the "don't work" setup right? Can you add e.g. the output of ipconfig or a screenshot of the connection info details (whatever that shows the host side IP et.al.)?

Comment: Yes, Now I Have "Don't work" setup in Win 11 & Here's ```ipconfig``` result https://i.ibb.co/grzWT22/Screenshot-2022-04-27-143734.png

Comment: Can you also see if `Get-NetNatExternalAddress` gives you any output? If it does, please add the output to your question as well.

Comment: Yap, It gives me a lot of ExternalAddresses Info, Is it important to attach output?

Comment: Hmm a lot. Well you can see if there's one that NAT the WSL subnet to your LAN IP. What I suspect is that for some reason Windows doesn't add that automatically when you change the NIC connection from the PON to the router (or the PON one doesn't get removed but overrides the newly added NAT object). To be frank, I'm not familiar with WSL, so I'm really just looking for any potential hiccup.

Comment: By the way, [private IPs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses), and IMHO also [CGNAT IPs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT#Shared_address_space), are not at all sensitive. Redacting them are completely pointless (and only hinders others from isolating the problem).

Comment: Have you tried the `resolv.conf` solutions? You could try to disable temporarily the Windows Defender Firewall? You could also try to install another fresh instance of Ubuntu or (even better) another distro under WSL2.

Comment: I tried ```resolv.conf``` but found another problem. After setting ```/etc/wsl.conf``` ```[network] generateResolvConf = false``` and set my default gateway on ```/etc/resolv.conf``` or just ```nameserver 1.1.1.1``` after reboot the manually created ```/etc/resolv.conf``` file got deleted. Every time I restart it's gone :(   [Tried this one but failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323446/file-etc-resolv-conf-deleted-on-every-reboot-why-or-what) 

- Windows Defender Firewall (doesn't work)
- Another distro under WSL2 (same problem)

Comment: It's been a while but I had the same problem. I removed /etc/resolv.conf (because it was a link) created the resolve.conf I wanted (nameserver 8.8.8.8) and set the immutable bit for resolve conf (chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was resolved as soon as I turned off the ipv6 protocol in ethernet properties.

--EDIT--
Please note that this is not a permanent/"real" solution. It seems to work only right after you disable the ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

WSL2 connects to the internet unless its configuration is broken.

While the healthiest way to achieve this might be to read the [WSL2 Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) very carefully and go step-by-step,
I think that my thoughts on my own recent experiences can be helpful at the experience level.

As stated in some comments.
Network connections of WSL and WSL2 are different,
When WSL works directly as a bridge,
It works with WSL2 Nat or similar mechanism. (A nice example of backwards compatibility!)

After a few unsuccessful attempts with WSL2, I was in the same situation, after researching and trying again, I found that I could set the WSL distribution or the WSL version in general if necessary.

`wsl --set-version <distro name> 2`

`wsl --set-default-version 2`

WSL --> WSL2 version confusion can cause problems.

Hyper V adds some adapters for WSL and WSL2.
I tried to edit the network adapters, as HyperV Bridge Adapter style devices added affected my IP addressing system,
I started having problems on the network, and started fiddling with the settings. At this point I lost WSL2's internet output.
When I recreated the network adapters via HyperV, the problem was solved.
If you can check the network adapters and examine them in detail - ip addresses, gateways etc. -

Over time, we may have the opportunity to create a working sample video presentation if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Uable to download any apt update/upgrade. Always times out.

- WSL2 LTS 22.04.1
- IP correct
- DNS working

Issue is with WSL2. Easy fix.

At the DOS command prompt

```
wsl -l -v
```

Get the distro name:

```
wsl --set-version <distro name> 1
```

Takes a few mins to connect to v1.

Do a restart and it all should work fine.

Comment: I want to fix it not to change it, though it's working now(without even doing anything, maybe they had fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

For me enabling mirrored networking mode solved the connectivity issues:

Edit `%UserProfile%\.wslconfig` to include:

```
[wsl2]
networkingMode=mirrored
```

Then restart distributions with `wsl --shutdown`. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#mirrored-mode-networking this has the following benefits:

- IPv6 support
- Connect to Windows servers from within Linux using the localhost address 127.0.0.1
- Improved networking compatibility for VPNs
- Multicast support
- Connect to WSL directly from your local area network (LAN)